# javascript immutables filter for unique student object by studentId field

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutables-library

I am new to using type script and immutables. I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

I have an object of the below type

```
export interface StudentProperties {
  studentId: number;
  studentName: string;
  active: boolean;
  subjects : string;
}
export interface Student extends TypedRecord<Student>, StudentProperties { }
```

I have a list of students immutable List students . Since a student can do more than one subject, I have the studentId and StudentName repeating across subjects

I want to return a List that has only the first Student for the studentId in case there is already a Student object with the same studentId

Example

- studentId, StudentName, active, subject
- 1,Sam, true, Math
- 2,Mark, false, Math
- 1,Sam,true, English
- 4,Clark, true, English

My list of students I want to return should not include the Sam in the third row which has studentId 1 as there is already a studentId 1 that it has seen

Expected student objects in the list

- 1,Sam, true, Math
- 2,Mark, false, Math
- 4,Clark, true, English

What is the best way to filter for duplicate studentId and return a list of Student objects that are unique by studentId. If a studentId repeats, only consider the student object that is seen first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.reduce method.

Let's assume your array is in `data` variable.

```
const res = data.reduce((prev, curr) => { 
    const index = prev.findIndex((item) => item.studentId === curr.studentId);
    if(index === -1) {
       return [...prev, curr];
    }
    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```